# Does NVidia's 3D vision take any additional compute power?

Tags: stereo-3d

I'm pretty sure I can do the gaming I want to on an i3/550Ti.  This is under the gaming FPS doesn't need to be 120hz, only the display frequency.  This also assumes that the 3D equipment doesn't drop in-game framerates below what the hardware would normally be doing by itself.

So, my question:

Will given hardware perform the same framerate-wise with or without NVidia's 3D vision?

Comment: Clarification: are you asking if NVidia's 3D takes more system CPU resources or more of the card's resources?

Comment: Either, of a significant amount.  I consider significant any reduction in framerate of > 5% for the same hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, since 3d vision enabled games render twice as many frames (one for each eye, rather than just one for both eyes) you would expect the framerate to be roughly 50% of normal.

However, according to [this](http://www.hitechlegion.com/reviews/gaming-software/6185http://www.hitechlegion.com/reviews/gaming-software/6185), the Nvidia Fermi architecture (4xx and onwards) seems to have improved on this which reduces the performance loss to only 38%. I would expect this to vary depending on your hardware configuration and the particular game since different 3d engines stress different aspects of your hardware (CPU, fill rate, GPU memory bandwidth, etc.).

In your case, the GPU your are considering is mid-range so I would expect a significant performance loss when enabling 3d vision on modern games.

Comment: However, do consider that the "loss" in frames isn't straightforward: each eye is seeing fewer frames, but *you* still see all the frames. This means that your experience of the "lower" framerate will not be quite like a normal 50% or 38% drop.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's something like 38%.
However 3D Vision technic does not cause exact same amount performance loss for each components of computer
(Such components can be example: processor, rams on motherboard, gpu,/memorys in grapchic card, hard drives, everything what effects on the performance)

So the final performance loss can be less or more than 38% depending on the computer.

Comment: Hi Mikko, and welcome to Arqade!  Instead of providing an answer that restates a previous answer, gain some reputation and then up-vote an existing answer you agree with.  I realize that you don't have enough reputation to up-vote at the moment, but we really frown on having someone post basically the exact same answer as what's already posted.

Comment: @MBraedley: especially since that machine has flared into existance and been decomissioned already since I posted the question initially :)